# Meteor template in img src not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am aware that images are to be kept in the public folder and the public folder is not to be referenced. Here is what I'm working with and I cannot for the life of me figure out what bug is causing the images to not load.

HTML:

```
<body>
{{>carousel}}
</body>
<template name="carousel">

    <div class="carousel">
        <span class="back">
            <a href="#">Back</a>
        </span>
        {{>carouselImages}}
        <span class="forward">
            <a href="#">Forward</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="carouselImages">
    <img src="{{slide}}" height="200px" width="200px">
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
slideNumber = 0;



if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.carousel.events({
                'click .back': function(){
                    if (slideNumber == 0){
                        slideNumber = 4;
                    } else {
                        slideNumber++;
                    }
                },
                'click .forward': function(){
                    if (slideNumber == 4){
                        slideNumber = 0;
                    } else {
                        slideNumber--;
                    }
                }
        });

        Template.carousel.helpers({
            slide: function(slideNumber){
                switch(slideNumber) {
                    case 0:
                            return "21.png";
                            break;
                    case 1:
                            return "bj2.png";
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            return "vp.png";
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            return "vp2.png";
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            return "vp3b.png";
                            break;
                }
            }
        });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

Comment: Change "Template.carousel.helpers" to "Template.carouselImages.helpers", since carouselImages is the name of your template. Also, won't you need to pass the "slideNumber" arg to the helper function?

Comment: Updated it to reflect the entire code to answer your question. I tried changing the names as you suggested and passing the slideNumber arg to the helper function to no avail.

Comment: I don't get it. You are not providing the required argument to the `slide` helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to refer to a global variable (`slideNumber`) but provide a local overload (`slide: function(slideNumber)`), and you are not providing any arguments to `slide` in your template. Either remove the local argument (see below), or provide is somehow as argument.

```
Template.carouselImages.helpers({
    slide: function() {
        switch(slideNumber) {
           ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the event handlers aren't changing the image based on the Switch. I'm a little unsure as to why that is because I was under the assumption that the helper should be reactive. Do you know by chance?

Comment: yes, global variables are not a reactive datasource. I would use a reactiveVar or a session variable instead (but a reactivevar would be best). See the documentation on that here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg.